# Start video playback NOT enter full screen

Tags: safari, fullscreen

When I watch videos in Safari sometimes I want to stop the video and go to another tab, then I come back to the video and click on it to start the playback. But instead of the video starting I go to full screen. How do I stop this behavior?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. It would help us if you provided additional info, such as the types of devices, OS, etc.  Also let us know what you've already done to solve the problem yourself.  Please see [ask] for how to ask good questions that have a better chance at being answered. - From Review

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered that I can go to full screen with a double click. If the double click speed is too fast it won't do it so there has to be a couple seconds between clicks, so I think that what is happening is that I am clicking the tap where the video is and then clicking in the screen and the time between the two clicks is the right amount to put me in full screen. Now that I know this I can do another double click to exit full screen. I would still like to be able to disable tis if anyone knows how to do it.

Comment: Be sure to come back and [accept your own answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) as soon as possible.  This helps others and gives you [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).